# Converting java.sql.Timestamp to java.util.Calendar without losing precision

Tags: java, calendar, timestamp

I'm trying to fetch timestamp values from a database, convert them to Calendar, and convert them back to Timestamp, but they lose their precision.

Here's the code to reproduce the problem

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(112, 10, 5, 15, 39, 11, 801000000);
        System.out.println("BEFORE "+timestamp.toString());
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp.getTime());
        timestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("AFTER "+timestamp.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is the sample result of conversion

```
BEFORE 2012-10-18 14:30:13.362001
AFTER 2012-10-18 14:30:13.362
```

It loses its precision.
What do I do to keep the decimal value as it is?

Comment: I have tried this in my ide but i did not get such result, every time it prints same - `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
  System.out.println("1 -> "+timestamp);
//  Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp.getTime());
  timestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
  System.out.println("2 -> "+timestamp);`

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where do you get these timestamps, how do you output them?

Comment: I've updated the example, I'm sorry the false result before was my fault.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are setting the time in **milliseconds**, but your input precision is in **microseconds**, so of course you are going to lose any precision finer than milliseconds.

Calendar doesn't support finer granularity than milliseconds. There is no work-around.

Comment: And there is no alternative class either?

Comment: @William JodaTime is the usual response, but it too only supports milliseconds. Your requirement is a bit unusual - consider using millisecond granularity (like everybody else)

Answer (score 8):

## java.time

In Java 8 and later we now have a solution: the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built in. Defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

This new framework has [nanosecond](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. That's enough to handle the old java.util.Date values, Joda-Time values, both being [milliseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). And it's enough to handle the [microseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) used by some databases such as [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org). Some databases such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) use nanoseconds. So java.time can handle it all, or least all the mainstream situations. The only exceptions would be niche scientific or engineering situations.

[image]

With Java 8, the old classes got new methods for converting to/from java.time. On [java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) use the new `toInstant` and `fromInstant` methods. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class contains a count of nanoseconds from epoch, first moment of 1970 UTC (basically, see class doc for details).

From an `Instant` you can get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = myResultSet.getTimestamp( 1 );
Instant instant = ts.toInstant();
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```